# I have closed hibernate session but its giving me warning that session is not closed and may be its memory leak?

Tags: java, hibernate, session, jakarta-ee, resources

I am finding memory leaks in my hibernate application using eclipse memory leaks analyzer. I am doing everything proper but getting error at return statements of following function session may not be closed.
Here is my code

```
public static boolean insertLocalAccount() {
    boolean isInsertedSuccefully = false;
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Sync_FILE_LOGGER");
    logger.info("This is SyncLocalInsert -->  insertLocalAccount function");
    Session clientSession = HibernateUtilLocal.getSession();               
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Account> accountList = clientSession.createCriteria(Account.class)
        .add(Restrictions.eq("isUploaded", false))
        .setMaxResults(100)
        .list();
    if(accountList.size() > 0){                                 
        String json = new ConnectionUtil().ConvertStringToJSON(accountList);
        String flag =  new ConnectionUtil().CallWebService("saveAccountData", json);
        if(flag.trim().equals("true")){
            Transaction clinetTx = clientSession.beginTransaction();
            try {                               
                int i = 0;
                for (Account account : accountList) {
                    account.setIsUploaded(true);
                    clientSession.merge(account);
                    if (i % 50 == 0) {
                        clientSession.flush();
                        clientSession.clear();
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                clinetTx.commit();
                isInsertedSuccefully = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if (clinetTx != null) {
                    clinetTx.rollback();
                }
                Exception e1 = new Exception(e);
                logger.error("This is an error log entry SyncLocalInsert -->  insertLocalAccount function ", e1);
                isInsertedSuccefully = false;
            }  finally {
                if (clientSession != null) {
                    HibernateUtilLocal.closeSession();
                }

            }
        }
    }
    return isInsertedSuccefully;
}
```

At the return statement I am getting error `Potential resource leak: clientSession may not be closed at this location`

HibernateUtilLocal.java

```
public static Session getSession(){

 Session session = (Session) threadLocal.get(); 
 if (session == null || !session.isOpen()) {
    session=sessionFactoryLocal.openSession(); 

     threadLocal.set(session);
 }
 return session;
}

public static void closeSession(){
 Session session = (Session) threadLocal.get();
 threadLocal.set(null);
 if (session != null) {
     session.flush();
     session.close();

 }
```

}

Comment: @Khelwood I have edited pls check now..

Comment: Looks like `closeSession` is not called if `accountList` is empty.

Comment: What is HibernateUtilLocal ? Whats its implementation of   HibernateUtilLocal.closeSession()? You may want to close the "clientSession" explicitely.

Comment: @Alok sinha pls chek it now